# Can I increase height of app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way of increasing height of app bar according to safe area in flutter cause the text in Center looks weird.

Comment: I put a answer here.

Comment: isn't it work for you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this like using below code. Put `PreferredSize` widget as a parent of `AppBar` and set a height.

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
      child: AppBar(
        title: Text('appbar'),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use *toolbarHeight*

```
      AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 100,
      title: Text('Main Page')
    )
```